# Complex searches in KDE's Baloo?

Tags: kde, baloo

I see Baloo indexing my stuff.
I wonder:

How can I search in more complex ways ? (maybe directly through SQLite or sth?)

I wonder about, either sth "user comfortable" like advanced Gmail search operators (I imagine search requests like "content:(x y z) file:(.*pdf) -file:(a.*)") or at least sql (or other more powerful) interface.